# Should I use X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff on images?

Tags: explorer

I'm using  X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff security header on my project, but it broke my images on IE. All other file types work fine, except of images.

I suspect that IE is handling image differently that type specific in Content-Type header (i.e. image/jpeg). I assume it recognizes images as application/octet-stream as I'm returning array of bytes in my app logic.

One solution is to use nosniff for all content-types instead of images (image/jpeg/ image/png...).

Do you agree this is best solution for this case?
What type IE assumes for image when it is returned as byte array?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you find solution to this problem?